# Recently posted "low-quality" answers

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close Review Queue - recent questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148213/close-review-queue-recent-questions)

I have recently started reviewing "low-quality" posts, one thing which I see repeatedly are posts which have **only just been posted** *(perhaps 1-5 minutes previously)*.

It seems harsh to delete them so soon, and much more useful to comment (suggesting the user elaborate), especially if they are a new-user... and many users push an answer and then edit it immediately.

Should I "Looks good" new answers (if there is a glimmer of home they could/or will be edited shortly)? *Currently I err on the side of "not sure" (leaving it for the next guy to review...), but I feel I should be more decisive.* Is there a policy or any guidelines, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure what you should do, perhaps you should click the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button.

Comment: No as really what is wanted is a delay and see the question again in a couple of days - in otherwords the view of the question changes overtime - and as I note in my question it should not be closed immediately

Answer (score 0):

I would say to just evaluate them based on the quality of the answer. You can probably get a good indication of whether a further edit will be made (if it is somewhat low quality). If you think you could improve the answer by an edit, make a suggestion. If you think that the answer is beyond help, then use the voting buttons as you see appropriate.

Comment: "beyond help" is a rather low bar :) certainly if I can improve it myself I will, but if I don't understand it (and it could be correct) should I pass it on (click "not sure")?

Comment: @haydoni Well, I am mod, and only a user a few months, but if I am not sure, I am more than happy to hit that *Not Sure* button. I only choose an action if I am totally certain of the action.