# Language contrasting discussion closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, not-constructive

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432997/programability-of-java-vs-c-for-certain-games/13433063#13433063) was closed, and I don't understand how it's "not constructive".

I'm asking the differences between the 2 for the type of program I want to compile, as well as asking which is more similar to the languages I already know. Why would this be against anything?

Answer (score 6):

This question follows a specific pattern of not constructive questions that have also already been asked and answered, and that are also based on opinions, which can lead to extended discussion, debate, or arguments, as defined by the close reason, which is listed beneath every closed post:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

This question is similar to:

- What language should I learn next, Java or C++?
- Which is better, Java or C++?

On [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), the place where you should actually go to ask whiteboard questions, these questions are quickly closed because they don't solve a real problem. When looking at these types of questions after the smoke has cleared and everyone has moved on, it's never clear which langauge is actually better or which language one should learn next.

In fact, there's a blog post about this, called [Gorilla vs Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), that does a great job of explaining why these types of questions don't fit the Q&A format.

With that said, from reading your question, I see you mention that you've hit certain "pitfalls" in game development with certain languages.  So instead of asking for a single, catch-all, polling explanation from each and every individual who drops by your question, you should instead think about each problem you're facing as a completely separate individual question.

For instance, if you're having trouble with games written in Java lagging, maybe ask how you can speed them up, showing what you've tried and what results you're seeing. They may not be perfect questions, but they'd be better than simply asking people to list all the similarities and differences between the two languages.

What's more, you may actually find a *solution* to the problem. If that solution is "Java sucks for game development, use C++", then that's great, but the answer could also be "Increase the heap size" or something that involves using the features of the existing language. Hope this helps!

*As an aside, I saw in the comments, on your Stack Overflow question, that you asked why the question was not constructive; it seems it was not clear. Thus, you may be interested, as a new user, in weighing in on [this proposal to make it clear what closed actually means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152026/155826), as it seems the close reason, from a user interface perspective, is easy for people to miss.*

Comment: However, I've already read posts here about the differences,
and as I said, they sounded Greek to me.
The only thing I understood what "it depends on what you're doing".

So I listed WHAT I would be doing, so IT WOULDN'T be a duplicate,
asking for help, and asking which language is more similar.

I understand what you're saying about posting them as different questions, but I felt I wouldn't get the same overall outlook as I would posting the bigger picture.

Comment: Hi @Reidmere, you'd actually get better results as separate questions about more targeted problems. There would be less noise, and quite frankly, less debate about what would solve the problem. What's more, consider that it would be easier for other users to find from Google searches, and posting answers isn't the only way to give back to the community. In fact, asking great questions that will help future visitors is perhaps more beneficial, and more targeted questions are generally more helpful to others. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will just have to try that next time...
Would there be any rules against linking to another post when I ask a question, so that the question I'm asking a question about code, they can see what relevant code/engine I'm working on? Example: If I'm asking a question about how to increase performance for something, is it ok to post a link to the page that I asked for help on how to do 3D model/texture compiling, so they can see the manner of programming I used? Thanks :)

Comment: Sometimes people do link posts together as a reference, but the post should still stand on its own as well. The problems you're facing should be broken down enough to be self contained. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

To be more specific: "What language should I choose" is almost never a good question. Software development is all about knowing the basic methods of solving problems using computers. The language you use is often secondary because most problems can be solved in one way or another in most program languages.

The question then boils down to a careful consideration of the strengths and weaknesses of different program languages. What you think is the most important features of a language is subjective and depends enormously upon your specific situation, so nobody but you can choose confidently. Read up on the languages and what features they have. Make a small program in each of them and see what you think.

Comment: Thanks, but I did get a good answer on the question, about which would be simpler to learn handle memory with, without much cost of functionality, in this type of case.

I understand what you were saying, but it really didn't answer anything, because it didn't pertain to any of the actual questions. While I already knew what you are saying, I also know that there's good guidelines for what's "simpler" for certain things, similar to using HTML or CSS for certain styling features.